# Injecting from application.yml in camel processor

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm trying to inject values from the application.properties file in a camel processor but it returns `null`. I also tried adding the `@Component` annotation but this breaks the application.

```
public class MyProcessor implements Processor {
 @Value("${myProperty.path}")
  public String path;
  public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(path);
    }
}
```

I'm new to both camel and spring. What could I do to read properties from the application.properties file in the processor class?

Comment: Are you instantiating class MyProcessor with a new operator in you code? Can you please show your project structure. Also can you please double check the import you are using for Value, please make sure it is : import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

Comment: in your route, autowire the MyProcessor class, and reference the autowired object in .process()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property injection with `@Value` only works with container managed beans.

Therefore, you are on the right track with `@Component`, but I suspect (as mentioned in the comments) that your `MyProcessor` is not such a bean.

If you do one of these in your Camel route, then your Processor is NOT such a bean.

```
.process(MyProcessor.class)
.process(new MyProcessor())
```

Instead you have to annotate your Processor with `@Component`, hold an instance variable of it in your Camel Route class and then reference the instance.

```
.process(myProcessorInstance) <-- variable
```